# MVVM ObservableCollection inside a ObservableCollection (ViewModel)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I am just wondering how I can have a sub collection of a parent collection?

For example,

I already have a ObservableCollection of Products, which is adding and hen binding to the XAML correctly. However, now I need to have another ObservableCollection which contains product items.

Basically I am thinking in the view model of having something like

```
 ProductCollection[0].ProductItemCollection.Add(newProductitem);
```

How would I go about this in MVVM?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: What are you thinking of doing with "ProductItem" collection with respect to the xaml? Also I am assuming that binding your "Products" collection to xaml means you are binding it to some ItemsControl.

Comment: Hi samar, yes the products is binded to an DataGrid. 

I am going to have another datagrid of products items for each product. 

When a user clicks on a product row, a product item grid well then appear which will contain all the items of that product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for but...

Let's say you have two grids in your xaml. The first shows your porducts, the second the selected product's items.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="173*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="147*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
              Margin="10">
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductItemsCollection}"
              Margin="10"
              Grid.Row="1">
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

You have the classes declared

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Selecting a product from the first grid will update the second grid's itemsource in the VM like below

```
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _ProductsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsCollection
    {
        get{return _ProductsCollection;}
        set
        {
            _ProductsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductsCollection");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _ProductItemsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ProductItemsCollection
    {
        get {return _ProductItemsCollection; }
        set
        {
            _ProductItemsCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductItemsCollection");
        }
    }

    private Product _SelectedProduct = null;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get {return _SelectedProduct;}
        set
        {
            _SelectedProduct = value;
            ProductItemsCollection = _SelectedProduct.ItemsCollection;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }
```

Finally you add some sample data

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Product product1 = new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Product1" };
        product1.ItemsCollection.Add(new Item() { ID = 1, Date = DateTime.Now});
        product1.ItemsCollection.Add(new Item() { ID = 2, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) });

        Product product2 = new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Product2" };
        product2.ItemsCollection.Add(new Item() { ID = 3, Date = DateTime.Now });
        product2.ItemsCollection.Add(new Item() { ID = 4, Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) });

        ProductsCollection.Add(product1);
        ProductsCollection.Add(product2);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the example Raptis. However, on my 3rd day of MVVM I thought you did all the "collection logic" inside the VM.

So basically everything you have put inside the main window can go inside the VM?

Comment: Is is on the VM. Provide an example of how you thought it should be and we can have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, your right, I was going to say ignore that comment. Thanks. So is it best to use XAML to find the selected Item? I was usign C# to say var selectedItem = Grid.SelectedItem as Product.. I guess the whole point of XAML is to use it as much as possible?

Comment: You got it!
You can do it like "var selectedItem = Grid.SelectedItem as Product" but that means that the VM is aware of the datagrid. But it should not be. You'll find out that there is a binding property in xaml for everything you may need to communicate between xaml & VM. I think the most used are ItemsSource & SelectedItem.

Comment: @user3428422 please accept the answer if that is what you are looking for. Thanks!